# Jquery $.ajax json vs. getjson format

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a ajax call with json like this to get my data from php code and then display it in my page:

```
      function get_customerdata(custID){

        var serviceURL_customer = serviceURL + 'getcustomer.php';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: serviceURL_customer,
            async: false,
            data: {id : custID},
            dataType: 'json',

            success: onSucess_displaycust


        });

        return false;

    }

    // --------------------------------------------------
        function onSucess_displaycust(data)
    {

        var customer = data.item;

        $('#custname1').text(customer.Name1);

       ... // other code

    // --------------------------------------------------
    // PHP code

       $customer = $stmt->fetchObject();  

         ...

       $clean = utf8_string_array_encode($customer);

       echo '{"item":' . json_encode($clean) .'}'; 

       ...
```

I want to put the variable

> customer.Name1

in a div selector. This doesn't work.
When i fetch the same data with the same php-script with $.getjson it is working fine without problems. I have to use $.ajax cause of syncron fetching data.
Can anybody help to solve my problem?

This is a extraction of my json data:

```
 //------------------------------------------

        //json data

           1.   item: {ID:10011, UserID:XXX, Passwort:XXX, Name1:Bike Sport, Name2:XXX,…}

                 1. Name1: "Bike Sport"
```

This is the exact response of my json-data:

```
{"item":{"ID":"10011","UserID":"XXX","Passwort":"XXX","Name1":"Bike Sport", ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the JavaScript console in Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to see if there is an error? My guess is that the function onSucess_displaycust is undefined within the scope in which you are calling it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes i have checked this in Dev Tools, there are no errors. The function onSucess_displaycust ( wrong word success, i know) will be called correctly, i have debugged the function. I think there is a difference in the json-format comming from the php when calling with $.ajax or calling with $.getjson. But i can't see any differences.